# Find the the mean of several indexed lists at index values in R

Tags: r, list

I have 4 predicted y values presented as an indexed list in R:

```
> y_a
       2       12       15       19       20       22        3        4 
26.05434 24.33894 38.57935 37.94003 23.87608 46.20327 18.43043 24.96521 
       5        8       13       21        1        7       10       11 
17.34129 30.41087 28.49836 39.02917 21.96358 30.41087 23.61032 30.41087 
      16       18 
35.31196 35.85652 
> y_b
       6        9       14       17       23       24        3        4 
36.87726 35.30301 40.48044 38.24398 42.67726 41.31053 32.32106 33.81204 
       5        8       13       21        1        7       10       11 
32.07257 35.05451 40.31655 44.74850 38.82558 35.05451 27.80451 35.05451 
      16       18 
36.17274 36.29699 
> y_c
       6        9       14       17       23       24        2       12 
30.24043 35.33617 39.18723 33.63404 42.76170 39.36809 32.25106 24.04894 
      15       19       20       22        1        7       10       11 
39.34681 38.28298 31.01702 43.66596 33.19787 34.71915 27.60213 34.71915 
      16       18 
37.49574 37.80426 
> y_d
       6        9       14       17       23       24        2       12 
26.48159 35.12368 38.41591 31.00840 40.54660 36.01979 31.00840 22.70478 
      15       19       20       22        3        4        5        8 
40.47355 32.72757 29.36229 46.23494 25.24701 30.18534 24.42395 34.30063 
      13       21 
32.72757 33.55063
```

I would like to create a list that returns an average of the points on each list at the same index. In other words the average of point at index 2, index 12, index 15, and etc...

```
> y_mean
       2       6       9       12....     
26.05434  31.8664  ......      ......
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of such a list. (You appear to be showing 4 vectors, not a list?) Perhaps using `purrr`, `map_dbl(transpose(your_list), mean)`. If you don't have a list, make one with `your_list <- list(y_a, y_b, y_c, y_d)`

Answer (score 1):

We may get the elements in a `list`, then `stack` it to two column data.frame, `rbind` and do a group by `mean`

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, 
     lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^y_[a-z]$")), stack))
aggregate(values ~ ind, dat, FUN = mean)
```

---

Or use `tapply`

```
with(dat, tapply(values, ind, FUN = mean))
```

---

Or if there are only four vectors, just do

```
v1 <- c(y_a, y_b, y_c, y_d)
tapply(v1, names(v1), FUN = mean)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the `mget` solutions, but +1 for the last `tapply` solution.